# Show points on map with leaflet

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-leaflet

I have about 150k points in my database, I need to get them from the database with a axios req and then show them on a map.
My app using PERN framework.
What is the best way to build this route with nodejs and react leaflet?
There is any option to preform a pagination method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostGIS to insert and select data from the database. I did something like this on a personal project. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/gwerle/sharedgis-backend

https://github.com/gwerle/sharedgis-frontend

To select from database using PostGIS you can do something like this:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, ST_X(geom::geometry), ST_Y(geom::geometry) FROM table
```

You can add a marker in each point using the `<Marker>` tag (docs here https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker).

Comment: The problem I have 150k points. not the best solution.